# Correct xpath returns empty result

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape data from the table on this webpage http://www.changning.sh.cn/jact/front/front_mailpublist.action?sysid=9

Before writing a spider, I tested my Xpath expressions in Scrapy shell, but ran into one problem: Xpath can't get any text out of the table.

[image]

Say I want to extract the text LM2015122827458 in the upperleft cell, I used `response.xpath("//tr[@class = 'tr_css']/td[1]/text()").extract()`. Only an empty list was returned. I tried alternative Xpath expressions including the ones inspired by Chrome "copy Xpath," but had no luck. I even used `response.xpath("//text()")` to extract all the texts on the page to see if LM2015122827458 is there. It wasn't. So, is this a page that Xpath can't deal with? Or did I do something wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: The table contents are very likely loaded with Javascript, so they are not available if you just scrape the HTML source. You might want to use something like ScrapyJS (Splash).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Mathias. That's also what I suspected. But how can I make sure if the data are loaded with Javascript? I did find these  in the head element. <script language="JavaScript" src="./template/9/images/JS.js"></script> Does this mean the data are loaded with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath is working fine for me:-

```
//tr[@class='tr_css'][1]/td[@class='text-center'][1]
```

Below code work in java is working fine for me :-

```
    driver.get("http://www.changning.sh.cn/jact/front/front_mailpublist.action?sysid=9");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='tr_css'][1]/td[@class='text-center'][1]")).getText();
    System.out.println(a);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Shubham, thanks for your answer! But were you able to get anything through your Xpath? I used it in the following code but it still returned an empty list. `response.xpath("//tr[@class='tr_css'][1]/td[@class='text-center'][1]")`. And it's a  pity that I don't know Java so I can't benefit from your second code.